# Register a pre defined tree of taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, hierarchical

I want to use a certain defined tree of taxonomies like this:

- news
- stories

  - travel
  - people
  - nature
- videos

but I want to have this hierarchy set in the code and not created via admin interface. The user should only be able to add new posts linking them to the correct taxonomy.

I have found documentation about how to register a taxonomy which allows children, but not about how to define a full tree.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

The children are terms. First register your taxonomies (news, stories, videos), then register travel, people, and nature as terms under stories.

Like so: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term